# forward declaration of class using templates

Tags: c++, g++

Can I use forward declaration for template class?
I try:

```
template<class que_type>
class que;
int main(){
    que<int> mydeque;
    return 0;
}
template<class que_type>
class que {};
```

I get:

```
error: aggregate 'que<int> mydeque' has incomplete type and cannot be defined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward declaration of a class should have complete arguments list specified. This would enable the compiler to know it's type.

When a type is forward declared, all the compiler knows about the type is that it exists; it knows nothing about its size, members, or methods and hence it is called an **Incomplete type**. Therefore, you cannot use the type to declare a member, or a base class, since the compiler would need to know the layout of the type.

You can:

*1. Declare a **member** pointer or a reference to the incomplete type.

 2. **Declare** functions or methods which accepts/return incomplete types.

 3. Define functions or methods which accepts/return pointers/references to the incomplete type.*

Note that, In all the above cases, the compiler does not need to know the exact layout of the type & hence compilation can be passed.

Example of 1:

```
class YourClass;
class MyClass 
{
    YourClass *IncompletePtr;
    YourClass &IncompleteRef;
};
```

Comment: How to use references to incomplete type? Except as function return value?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a template issue.  You cannot use a type as a by-value variable unless it has been fully defined.

Comment: So.. I can use pointer to undefined class, but cant create object until body appears?

Answer (score 4):

No. At the point of instantiation, the complete definition of the class template must be seen by the compiler.  And its true for non-template class as well.