# Forward declaration of (sdk) class containing template

Tags: c++, templates, forward-declaration

I have been doing forward declarations in header files, and including the actual class files in cpp. But I run into problems when the classes are templated:

```
class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass();
  void aFunction();
private:
  QList<int> m_member;
};
```

To get it to build I need to give this class info about `QList`. I tried:

```
class QList;

error: template argument required for 'class QList'
```

I tried (because I will only need `QList` of integers in this particular class):

```
class QList<int>;

error: specialization of 'QList<int>' after instantiation
```

I have looked up these errors but found only issues with people having trouble creating class templates, found nothing about forward declarations.

If nothing else works, I can `#include <QList>` in the header file and give up on forward declaration - but I would like to understand this issue.

This option is also suggested in the most popular question about [template classes forward declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3879276/1217150):

> Just `#include <list>` and don't worry about it.

I don't understand [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7111301/1217150)...

Comment: If you want to have `QList<int>` as a member of your class, the full declaration is needed anyway (because the compiler will need to compute the size of your class). With a forward declaration you can have pointers or references, but not much more.

Comment: @BoPersson how can it do that if the size of the list is not known ?

Comment: The `QList<int>` object will always be of the same size. The `int`s in the list will be allocated separately.

Comment: The compiler errors you quote sound like `<QList>` has already been included, actually, so it won't hurt to include it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can forward declare a templated class, like this:

```
template<typename>
class QList;
```

But it wont work if you declare a member with this type (i.e. m_member) that is not a reference or a pointer.

Comment: Oh so if I want this my private members need to be references... hat would work... would I have to declare them as `QList<typename>*m_list` ?

Comment: @Thalia, right (pointer or reference), because just like with any forward declaration, it does not define a complete type.